# Change @media perception of min-width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap and don't want to re-invent the wheel. I have implemented my page inside a container (div) which is smaller than the frame.

The result is that bootstrap doesn't properly adapt (navbar for example) to the container because it uses @media(min-width:...) which defines the width from the frame and not the container. How can I change the @media perception of the frame to be the one of my container?

Comment: can u create a fiddle demo?

Comment: That would require using something like [element queries](http://responsiveimagescg.github.io/eq-usecases/), but those don't exist yet.

Comment: @cvrebert Crap, I thought there would be a handy dandy solution!

Comment: Isn't the Web wonder^W horrible? :-)